Best way to run cat 6 flat network cable under house
I need to run a flat cat 6 network cable from one corner of my house to the opposite corner.

I'm thinking of drilling a hole through the floor near the corner, dropping the cable through, then crawling through the crawlspace (dragging the cable) to the opposite corner of the house and drilling another hole there.
I've been underneath.  It is a triple-wide manufactured home.  It sits on thick I-beam rails standing on jackstands and cinder blocks.  Laying on my back looking up, I see some kind of black fabric holding up insulation.


I'm apprehensive about drilling down through my floor and into/through insulation.
What is the best way to run this flat cat 6 network cable under the house?

Are you open to other suggestions, like using WiFi or powerline adapters? I'm curious: why didn't you have the internet line terminated where you wanted it instead of doing this?

I have a real basement, and for the ground floor using surface-mount jacks and running the ethernet cable down through the floor and across the joists to the hub was by far the simplest solution, saving me a bit of hassle running it thru the wall. For the top floor I ran cable up alongside the chimney to the attic and across ceiling joists, then down through the wall to a jack plate.

To hide wires, you can take that box off of the wall and drill the hole into the wall plate.  It is neater and there are longer drill bits for this situation.  The baseboard on the floor can also be removed and drill the hole behind it.

I would have liked to get it installed on the back corner of the house, but the fiber guy wouldn't do it.  He wanted the shortest line from the pole to the house.  He installed it right next to the old internet line from the previous owners.  This is what I have to work with.

"A flat Cat6 cable" is 99.63% going to be a patch cable. Better to use robust cable actually intended for the purpose of being fixed building wiring, rather than delicate cable only intended for use outside of concealed spaces and with plugs attached to the ends that force you to drill oversized holes. As for foaming a hole drilled in the base of the wall, you can foam it from where the cable comes out underneath the house. You can also access from the top by removing the baseboard. As for hanging the cables under a metal framed house; bridle rings -https://diy.stackexchange.com/a/298307/18078

what is the device in the picture? ... what is the white cable, and where does it lead?

A fiber modem and its power cable, (so to an outlet where the transformer end of it is plugged in) pretty sure from context, @jsotola

How did THAT cable get into the house, and can't you use the same hole?

@Ecnerwal Common misconception. Patch cable is more robust. The big thing is it's stranded, so it tolerates frequent bending. Installed cable is solid, it's cheaper, thinner, the loss is somewhat lower, and it can be used in punchdown blocks. The analogy is Romex vs a power cord, you can't use Romex as an extension cord.

Would this cable be better?: https://www.amazon.com/GearIT-Gold-Plated-Connectors-Resistant-Waterproof/dp/B08P2SVTW7/

The device on the wall is the fiber "modem".  I have a 5 gigabit connection and I want to use as much of it as I can.  The blue network cable is what the installation guy left me.  I'm not going to use it.  The white cord is the power.  There is no outlet in range of this box, so I have a short power strip laying on the floor just out of frame.

I think when I retire, I might start a business of fixing telcom installs... where they never remove old dead runs and then fixing the run inside the house because they always screw you over by always wanting the shortest line from the pole to the house.  Want some amusement, drive around the bad/poor part of town and observe how some cable runs are done on the outside of homes, especially rentals.

without a building schematic, can't answer your subject question.  Sorry to say the simplest solution here is to get a wifi6 mesh style router and stick it there on the floor.  The TP link deco for example you can get satellite units that will then offer an rj45 port to run cable (cat6) to a device that can't do wireless.  The other common ones are eero which the installer typically gives you with the install to solve this problem you are describing.

if you did not make it clear during the install, the installer kept the eero you were supposed to get, and is selling it off on the side for a buck

As far as I can tell, "flat cable" is really meant for patch cables. Patch cables should always be easily accessible because the ends will go bad over time, particularly if the cable is hard to replace.
The right way to do this is:

Install a jack at each end. This can be a wall jack in a junction box or a box eliminator or it can be in a surface mount box.
Run outdoor rated cable (i.e., UV resistant and waterproof, and hopefully slightly more critter-proof than the standard stuff) between the two jacks.
Punch down the cable to each jack using a punch tool:



Test the cable. For occasional use, a cheap tester like this one is fine:



Use short factory-made patch cables (I don't care if they are flat or not) to connect to the router or switch or whatever device on each end. If those patch cables go bad they cost almost nothing to replace.


If the fiber modem side is not planned to be disturbed after installation, you can punch the jack directly on the outdoor cable and plug it into a box, without adding a wall socket. DO USE a wall socket on the other side and make sure the cable is properly fixed to the wall so it doesn't get damaged by vacuum cleaner or such.

I'd skip the punch down tool and simply use female-female keystones in the jack.  Sure, you bored hole may need to be bigger, but you're guaranteed that the wiring is right.

@Huesmann Your solution implies using ready-made patch cords, and from experience, long patchcords tent to be of poor quality leading to very low transfer speeds. It is better to buy actual copper cat6 wiring from reputable seller (electric hardware store, they sell by meters or feet). It will be also hard to find outdoor rated patch cord. Punching cable down is not trivial, but you can always redo it, just leave enough slack on both sides (slack can be slid down the hole under house)

@Thomas I have had no problems buying quality long patch cords.  OP probably needs no more than 100' of cable.

Punch-down jacks available in the home centers often include a very usable punch-down tool. For example: https://www.homedepot.com/p/Commercial-Electric-Category-5e-Jack-White-5025-WH/206427940. I'd hate to use one for 8 hours a day, but for installing two jacks, not a problem. And if you just follow the wire color chart printed on the jack, it's hard to get it wrong.

The approach your question asks is fine: drill a hole down and poke it through the insulation and the fabric. A long piece of stiff wire or a fish tape might help.
Personally, if I decided I was going through the effort to pull wire I would try and do it inside the wall instead of having 6-8" of wire showing between the wall and floor.

Some kind of long flexible drill line with a spade bit on the end?  I thought about that, but it would be difficult to get a grommet in there, or expanding foam.  I don't want the hole inaccessible inside the wall but very accessible so I can use a grommet and/or expanding foam to seal it up to keep the bugs out.

Yes, they make long bits just for this purpose. As the other answer states, if having it in your floor is acceptable, aside from aesthetics or having it prone to damage by being exposed are the only reasons to put it in the wall.

You can cut in a "low voltage ring" next this box, nice and close to the floor, and the same on the end you are going to, and use the holes from those for convenient access to the base of the wall (inside) so you don't need an absurdly long bit. You can also mount jack plates on the low voltage rings, use solid Cat6 cable, and terminate it to jacks - then just use short patch cords to connect the fiber modem and whatever is at the other end to the jacks in the wall plates.

Just be careful that the 120V line is out of the way cutting into the wall.

@spuck hopefully any 120V cables will be easily visible once the OP cuts the hole in the wall for the low voltage ring.

@Huesmann but how is OP going to see them for the process of cutting into the wall? Versus say, cutting into said 120V lines?

@DoktorJ if it's a huge concern, you bore a hole and throw in an endoscope camera, giving it a 360º twirl.

@Huesmann By using a utility knife or short saw blade, instead of the 6" sawzall.  If a drywall saw is available, you use 1"-2" of the tip and take your time.

Your way is perfectly fine.  Minimal cost and effort, gets the job done, and there's nothing wrong with it.  Any other way needs to be justified.
Think about how you'll attach the wire to the underside of the house.  Don't use a stapler.  Lying on your back with your arms outstretched, I promise you'll miss and wreck the wire before the job is done.  Best to use wire ties where possible or to loosely pre-nail plastic wire staples before the wire is installed, then hammer them in later.
If you want to make more effort for diminishing returns, there is nothing wrong with doing these things either especially if they make you happy:

Fill the holes in the floor with colored caulk or plastic wall bushings or both
Cut off, and reattach the RJ45 connector so the holes can be smaller.  This will require $15 of tools and a few hours of learning and practice.
Use solid cable instead of stranded patch cord, put low voltage junction boxes and RJ45 sockets in the walls and drill through the floor plates inside the walls instead of the hardwood.
Run cables from both locations to a central patch bay. Put a switch there.
Consider using Mesh instead of hard wiring.

Responding to the comment that the  structure is metal I-Beams and there is nothing to attach to.  If truly there is nothing, anywhere, that you can attach with a zip tie, and the only things exposed are the beams, insulation between them and cinder blocks, you'll have to clamp to the beams.  Actual I-beam clamps exist, and are outrageously expensive for this project. Use binder clips!  Choose a size that's small enough that when you clamp it to the beam edge, it clamps firmly.  Zip tie the cable to the handle. Loosely at first, then when the job is done tighten them.

"Cut off, and reattach the RJ45 connector so the holes can be smaller. This will require $15 of tools and a few hours of learning and practice." This isn't a great idea -- pre-manufactured cables generally use stranded wire, and termination/crimp kits meant for one-off hand-tool use are generally best on solid wire. You will have trouble getting good high-speed performance. There are good ways to make long cable runs with hand termination, but they involve wiring wall jacks, not hand-crimping cable ends.

On the subject of attaching the cable to the underside... there is no wood, only metal.  How do I attach the cable to these steel beams?

+1 for @GlennWillen's comment. It is difficult to meet Cat6 specifications crimping by hand. Not impossible, but without a tester you don't know. Good enough for a home network? Probably. Using the punch-down wall jacks are a great way to go.

@GlennWillen and spuck you're both correct.  If actual Cat6 performance mattered this wouldn't fly.  But if you have 1Gb interfaces and 50ft of cable this will work just fine.  Leaving the cable intact is a better idea. Wall jacks are more work and expense.

If 1 gigabit is all you need, Cat5e is all you need...

When drilling the holes, keep the sawdust. When filling the holes, use a white filler and mix in your sawdust.

If you have some cat 5e lying around that's great. If you're buying it you'll save maybe $2. Sure.  If your colorizing your own filler for a 1 mm gap around a cable, your wife probably has better things for you to do.  :). We seem to be in diminishing returns here.

If you buy the cheapest 5e you can find on Amazon, and also reattach RJ45s after only an hour of YouTube training with no experience, and also use too small bend radiuses here and there, you may find yourself quietly knocked down to 10Gb.  You'll probably never know ;). But these things are cumulative. If you do everything perfectly the capability is far more than you probably need, so you have a little room for shortcuts.  Just don't take them all.

Responding to comment, "there is no wood, only metal" by adding to the Answer.

@Ecnerwal but who knows if >Gb will be available in the future—using Cat6 or better doesn't cost too much more.

@Huesmann at the risk of straying -- if any successful and widespread application arises for >1Gb residential bandwidth I'd bet it will be mostly wireless, and certainly won't rely on everyone having well-executed Cat6 or better cabling all over the place.  And if OP has a specific personal need for that ... the question would hopefully say so.

@jay613 but wireless speeds (almost?) always lag behind potential wired speeds.

Yet another use for binder clips!!

What do y'all think about using LTT Stores magnetic cable tie holders and put those onto the I Beams? https://www.lttstore.com/products/mcm-cabletieholder

I nearly flagged @Christian's post as self-promotion but seems to be an actual user.  IDK.  Anyway I think it's too expensive and not secure enough.  You could run conduit for less.  I think it's too expensive for literally anything.

@jay613 yes I'm a real user. Magnets just seemed an obvious solution to attaching things to steel. There might be cheaper ways than LTT.

If you want magnetic and cheap you've come to the right place!   ;)


I'm apprehensive about drilling down through my floor and into/through insulation.

Once you've drilled through the wood/metal part use a needle (or needle-like tool) to go through the soft parts because fabric and fibre insulation will tend to bunch up if you try to drill it.

What is the best way to run this flat cat 6 network cable under the house?

Four least jankiest, best first
A cable tray is massive overkill for a single wire, only included here because you asked for "best"
A catenary might be more suited to your scale,  string a plastic coated steel wire along the path and tighten it using a turnbuckle then attach the cat6 to the wire. you'll need eye bolts (or eye brackets) at each end to attach the caternary
Run a wooden stick the whole way screwing or clamping it to the beams, attach the cat6 to the side with cable saddles.
There's  a bunch of different folded metal clips that can be used attach cables to I beams but you may end up with some wire droop when crossing between beams
What I did under a wooden floor was put some elastic bands on my staple gun to hold zip ties over the business end, so that I could use both hands to staple zip ties to the floor beams (my manual staple gun needs both hands) then my I could put my CATx cables into the zip ties and close them up,  this was by no means "best" but I consider it sufficient.  were I to do this again I would use double sided hook-and-loop cable ties instead of zip ties.
Fencing staples are another option if you want something stronger than a staple gun can drive, find a way to hold them that does not endanger your fingers, aim is hard when lying on you back in a cramped location

An alternative, buy some flat white cable clips (bell wire clips might work well):

Then pin your cable along your skirting boards, something like this (but not grey):

A similar alternative, buy cabling trunking and attach it to your wall above your skirting boards:


Another option: quarter round cable raceway, e.g. https://www.homedepot.com/p/Commercial-Electric-5-ft-1-4-Round-Baseboard-Cord-Channel-White-A60-5W/304502804

I love the black wire on the white baseboard.  If you practice this enough you could go back and install cable TV in 1985!

I fact, there are flat cat 6 cables that could simply run under the carpet. (If there is carpet.)

No carpet whatsoever.  But I might add it later.  The whole house echos quite a bit.

Taking suggestions from lots of responses, I did this:

Drilled a 1 inch hole 6 inches from each corner with a regular spade bit.
Used a fiberglass fish-tape stick thingy (technical term) to push through the insulation and fabric.
Underneath, I attached one end of the cable to the fish-tape stick thingy.
Back up inside, I pulled the cable up through the hole.  There was plenty of room.


Then I did the same thing for the other end and connected up my router & switch.

Underneath, I used binder clips and zipties to suspend the cable off the ground:



It works great:

This is about half my available bandwidth because this computer only has a 2.5Gb ethernet port.  It's also the only computer I own with a 2.5Gb ethernet port.  If I ran three other computers (each with a standard 1Gb ethernet port) at the same time, all running speed tests, I could probably max out my connection.
I've added these simple 1-inch grommets:

The other side (the far corner of the house) is really coming along:

